# How can I regenerate token in pnp/sp v 3.14

Tags: sharepoint

I am developing an app to upload 6000+ rows. Each row will have its own permissions. I am using pnp/sp v 3.14. Cannot go back to old version(too many changes)

I get following error after 30 min of execution
Error2 70693 adding permissions 19 Error making HttpClient request in queryable [403] ::> {"odata.error":{"code":"-2130575252, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again."}}}

Here is my code

```
const sp2 = spfi().using( SPBrowser({ baseUrl: props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl }) ).using(RequestDigest());
    
for(let i=0;i<item_data_id.length;i++)
{
  id =item_data_id[i].id;
  per=item_data_id[i].permissions;
  await assignPermissionsbyID(id,per,roleDefId,froleDefId,current_user,sp2);
}

async function assignPermissionsbyID(id:number,permission_ids:Array<number>,roleDefId:number,froleDefId:number,current_user: ISiteUserInfo,sp:SPFI):Promise<void>
{
  //const sp = spfi().using( SPBrowser({ baseUrl: props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl }) );
  
  const list_id=props.list_id.trim();
  /*const headers = {
    Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    timeout: "60000", // set the timeout in milliseconds
  };*/
  const list = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(list_id);
  try
  {
    await list.items.getById(id).breakRoleInheritance(false);
    await list.items.getById(id).roleAssignments.add(props.owner_g_id,froleDefId);
    let pid=0;
    for(let i=0;i<permission_ids.length;i++)
    {
      pid=permission_ids[i];
      try
      {
        
        await list.items.getById(id).roleAssignments.add(pid,roleDefId);
        updateStatus("Assigning Permission -&gt; item id="+id+" permission id="+pid);
  
      }catch(e){
        msg=msg+"<span style='color:red' contenteditable='true'>Error2 "+id+" adding permissions "+pid+" "+(e.message)+"</span><br/>";
        message(msg);
      }
    }
    await list.items.getById(id).roleAssignments.remove(current_user.Id,froleDefId);
    
  }catch(e)
  {
    msg=msg+"<span style='color:red' contenteditable='true'>Error1 "+id+" adding permissions "+(e.message)+"</span><br/>";
    message(msg);
  }
  /*
  try
    {
      await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(list_id).items.getById(id).roleAssignments.add(props.owner_g_id,froleDefId);
      for(let i=0;i<permission_ids.length;i++)
      {
        try
        {
          await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(list_id).items.getById(id).roleAssignments.add(permission_ids[i],roleDefId);
          updateStatus("Assign Permission item id "+id+" permission id "+permission_ids[i]);
        }catch(e){
          msg=msg+"<span style='color:red' contenteditable='true'>Error "+id+" adding permissions "+permission_ids[i]+" "+(e.message)+"</span><br/>";
          message(msg);
        }
      }
      await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(list_id).items.getById(id).roleAssignments.remove(current_user.Id,froleDefId);
    }catch(e)
    {
      msg=msg+"<span style='color:red' contenteditable='true'>Error "+id+" "+(e.message)+"</span><br/>";
      message(msg);
    }
  */
  
  
}
```

The new documentation says spbrowser may work but it is not working in my case
https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/behaviors/#spbrowser
ref https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/2186

import { spfi, SPBrowser } from "@pnp/sp";
import "@pnp/sp/webs";

// you should use the baseUrl value when working in a SPA to ensure it is always properly set for all requests
const sp = spfi().using(SPBrowser({ baseUrl: "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev" }));

await sp.web();

It is a web based app (Single page application), which will run 40- 80 mins. It is timing out after 30min

How can I extend time in pnp/sp v 3.14

Answer (score 0):

public onInit(): Promise {

```
return new Promise<void>((resolve: () => void, reject: (error: any) => void): void => {
  const digestCache: IDigestCache = this.context.serviceScope.consume(DigestCache.serviceKey);
  digestCache.fetchDigest(this.context.pageContext.web.serverRelativeUrl).then((digest: string): void => {
    sp.setup({
      sp: {
        baseUrl: this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl,
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "X-RequestDigest": digest
        }
      },
      spfxContext: this.context,
      globalCacheDisable: true
    });
    resolve();
  });
});
```

}